# Why does `npm install` add / remove caret (^) to / from version numbers?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a project that I work on with two different laptops. Sometimes I add extra packages to my project, so I have to use `npm install <package-name>` (duh). When I do that, I `git push` up the new `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files, and when I switch computers I have to `git pull` those changes, then run `npm install` again to get that package onto the other computer.

I recently noticed and started caring that one laptop kept adding carets (`^`) to the beginning of every package version number. For example:

One computer set package version #s to look like this:

```json
"regexpu-core": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/regexpu-core/-/regexpu-core-1.0.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-hqdj9Y7k18L2sQLkdkBQ3n7ZDGs=",
  "requires": {
    "regenerate": "1.4.0",
    "regjsgen": "0.2.0",
    "regjsparser": "0.1.5"
  }
},
```

The other set package version #s to look like this:

```json
"regexpu-core": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/regexpu-core/-/regexpu-core-1.0.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-hqdj9Y7k18L2sQLkdkBQ3n7ZDGs=",
  "requires": {
    "regenerate": "^1.2.1",
    "regjsgen": "^0.2.0",
    "regjsparser": "^0.1.4"
  }
},
```

I understand that carets (`^`) mean the version is not 100% precise, but I'm trying to figure out **WHY** my different laptops create different formats for package versions! I checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) which has some great explanations for the differences between `~` and `^`, but I didn't find anything explaining why `npm` would sometimes add and sometimes remove carets (`^`) altogether. I also looked at [this npm issue on Github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19211) which recommended looking at `npm` config settings, but both of my laptops have the same settings:

- `npm config get save` = `true` (both computers)
- `npm config get save-prefix` = `^` (both computers)
- `npm config get save-exact` = `false` (both computers)

One laptop was running `npm` version `5.6.0`, but I just updated it to `6.5.0`. The other computer was running version `6.4.1`, but I also updated it to `6.5.0`. I tried running `npm install` in my project on both computers, but still I find that one computer always removes `^` and the other always adds `^`.

Please let me know if there's something I'm missing. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** According to the discussion in issue [#20434](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20434) this occurs by design using npm `>=6.0.0`.

***Why does this happen?***
[@rarkins](https://github.com/rarkins) elaborately explains the reasoning for why this happens (and it’s advantages) in [this comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20434#issuecomment-402988364). For convenience his comment is quoted below (verbatim):

> *Let's say that you use pinned versions of dependencies 'aaa', 'bbb' and 'ccc'. Let's say they each depend on 'zzz' like so:*
>
> - *aaa depends on zzz@^1.0.0*
> - *bbb depends on zzz@^1.1.0*
> - *ccc depends on zzz@^1.0.1*
>
> *i.e. all three of them depend on a range of zzz, and not an exact version.*
>
> *And let's say that the latest version of zzz is 1.5.0.*
>
> *Both before and after this change, it's pretty obvious that the resolved version of zzz should be 1.5.0, so the only difference is how the `package-lock.json` is structured and documents this sub-dependency.*
>
> *Before, the lock file would show that all three of them depend on zzz@1.5.0, and the resolved version of z is 1.5.0.*
>
> *Now, it documents the actual "original" dependency versions (e.g. ^1.0.0, ^1.1.0, etc) for each dependency, but still shows the resolved version of z as 1.5.0.*
>
> *Then consider what happens when zzz@1.5.1 is released:*
>
> *Before, the lock file would need to update from z@1.5.0 to z@1.5.1 in all four places.*
>
> *Now, the lock file only needs to update the resolved version of z to 1.5.1 while the dependencies can keep the ^1.0.0, ^1.1.0, and ^1.0.1 because they haven't changed.*
>
> *As I mentioned previously in the thread, you still get the exact same node_modules in both cases. The advantages of the new approach are:*
>
> 1. *You get to see what the dependencies actually require (e.g. a range, and not an exact version). before, you could not tell if aaa actually required exactly zzz@1.5.0 or that it was instead zzz@^1.0.0.*
> 2. *Instead of four lines changing in the lock file, you get only one. It's less churn, and it's more clear what's happened.*
>
> *As an aside, `yarn` uses a similar concept with `yarn.lock`. e.g. here's an example where `@sindresorhus/is` is pinned, but it's sub-dependency symbol-observable is not:*
>
> ```
> "@sindresorhus/is@0.10.0":
>  version "0.10.0"
>  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@sindresorhus/is/-/is-0.10.0.tgz#f42dd6a9d12cd79fa6f53b27cf5bea3a30d2cafa"
>  dependencies:
>    symbol-observable "^1.2.0"
> ```

---

**Original Answer:**

After you `git pull` the revised *package.json* and *package-lock.json* onto computer two try deleting the *node_modules* directory before installing the packages again.

For example:

1. Firstly `cd` to your project directory on computer 2.
2. Delete the existing *node_modules* directory by running: `rm -rf node_modules`.
3. Then run: `npm install`

Or you can chain the two aforementioned commands using the `&&` operator:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

Comment: This does not answer the question _why_ npm adds/remove the caret (^) from the versions in the lock file on `npm i` .. Too bad, because I run into the same issue and don't need the workaround, but I want to know _why_ this happens (and how it can be made consistent with/without node_modules dir)

Comment: @KlaasvanderWeij - I suggest either; asking a new SO question and provide a reference to this question, or ask npm directly via their Github repo. However, firstly read through the comments for issue [#20434](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20434). According to comments; [A](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20434#issuecomment-392346742) and [B](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20434#issuecomment-392421024), it occurs by design using npm `>=6.0.0`, i.e. it's intentional. Comment [C](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20434#issuecomment-402988364) provides further detail on why npm does this.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the GitHub issue and indeed comment C explains the _why_ of this elaborately