# Installing package with "@latest" removes semantic versioning

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, semantic-versioning

If I am installing a package using the `@latest` option the semantic versioning found for this package in the *package.json* is removed.

I have removed the `package-lock.json` file and the `node_modules` folder before doing the installation and this is still happening.

`package.json` before:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@awesomeproject/my_dep": "^1.0.4”,
}
```

Running:

```sh
npm install @awesomeproject/my_dep@latest
```

`package.json` after

```
"dependencies": {
  "@awesomeproject/my_dep": "1.0.5",
}
```

*expected*:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@awesomeproject/my_dep": "^1.0.5",
}
```

This is affecting only one specific package consistently. Other packages in the project are not affected, leading me to believe that this is something from that package and not from the project that is trying to update it. It should not be a problem changing anything in this package since I am the owner.

This is not the same problem as this question:
[Why does `npm install` add / remove caret (^) to / from version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091452/why-does-npm-install-add-remove-caret-to-from-version-numbers)
Since this is affecting all the packages.

**EDIT**:
I want to save the newest version of the package to the `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--no-save` flag which prevents the update happening in your `package.json`

You need to run the command as,

```
npm install @awesomeproject/my_dep@latest ---no-save
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi David R, this works. However I want to save the newest version in the package.json. I'll update the question to reflect this.