# npm install automatically add ^(caret) in package-lock

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

Previously relevant part in package-lock was looking this way

```
"requires": {
    "@babel/highlight": "7.0.0"
  }
```

But now it includes the caret(^) after running npm install.

```
"requires": {
    "@babel/highlight": "^7.0.0"
  }
```

(note - this contains only a small potion of package-lock)

Can anyone explain the reason for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`npm install\` add / remove caret (^) to / from version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091452/why-does-npm-install-add-remove-caret-to-from-version-numbers)